# Pushing each div into array and later joining them to html alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code which loops through a array, then pushes each div into a array. Later it will join then into a html. Problem with this one is, each div will come under each other, but I would like them to come all separated. Example: each class called `cf-skin` is under other `cf-skin` but I would like them all be on their own on the `cf-creator-skins`. If you wonder how I got the `way` how I want it, then I used `append`, but I actually can't use it because I have the JS code under a button and if I click it again, it's gonna just append again and everything will be twice there. Here is my JS code. I hope it was understandable

```
var data = findGame(id);
var skins_creator = [];
var skins_opponent = [];
$('.watch-cf .modal-header h3').html('Watch Coinflip | #' + id);
$('.modal-body #creator-name').html(data.creator[0].name);
$('.modal-body #hash').html(data.hash);
$('.modal-body .duel-user-img').attr('src', 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/1a/1a1b22711e4a3d5cededed01b24386ca6d181af4_full.jpg');
$('.modal-body #cf-creator-val').html(data.creator[0].totalSkins + ' skins valued at $' + data.creator[0].totalAmount);
data.creator[0].items.forEach(function (kevin){
    skins_creator.push('<div class="cf-skin" style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #'+kevin.color+'"> <div class="cf-skin-img"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/'+kevin.classid+'/111fx57f"></div><div class="cf-skin-name">'+kevin.name+'<p>'+kevin.price+' USD</p></div>');
});
$('.modal-body .cf-creator-skins').html(skins_creator.join(""));
$('.watch-cf').modal('show');
```

How these are at the moment.

```
<div class="cf-creator-skins">
    <div class="cf-skin" style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #undefined">
        <div class="cf-skin-img"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1611092744/111fx57f"></div>
        <div class="cf-skin-name">AWP | Lightning Strike (Factory New)
            <p>62.32 USD</p>
        </div>
        <div class="cf-skin" style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #eb4b4b">
            <div class="cf-skin-img"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/312020315/111fx57f"></div>
            <div class="cf-skin-name">★ Flip Knife | Safari Mesh (Battle-Scarred)
                <p>51.7 USD</p>
            </div>
            <div class="cf-skin" style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #undefined">
                <div class="cf-skin-img"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1815976823/111fx57f"></div>
                <div class="cf-skin-name">M4A1-S | Mecha Industries (Well-Worn)
                    <p>21.56 USD</p>
                </div>
                <div class="cf-skin" style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #undefined">
                    <div class="cf-skin-img"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/469585294/111fx57f"></div>
                    <div class="cf-skin-name">AK-47 | Vulcan (Well-Worn)
                        <p>21.46 USD</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cf-skin" style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #undefined">
                        <div class="cf-skin-img"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1011942928/111fx57f"></div>
                        <div class="cf-skin-name">AWP | Hyper Beast (Well-Worn)
                            <p>21.41 USD</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cf-skin" style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #undefined">
                            <div class="cf-skin-img"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1011942928/111fx57f"></div>
                            <div class="cf-skin-name">AWP | Hyper Beast (Well-Worn)
                                <p>21.41 USD</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cf-skin" style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #undefined">
                                <div class="cf-skin-img"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1812959668/111fx57f"></div>
                                <div class="cf-skin-name">M4A4 | Desolate Space (Minimal Wear)
                                    <p>18.16 USD</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="cf-skin" style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #undefined">
                                    <div class="cf-skin-img"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1440505236/111fx57f"></div>
                                    <div class="cf-skin-name">AK-47 | Point Disarray (Minimal Wear)
                                        <p>17.82 USD</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="cf-skin" style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #undefined">
                                        <div class="cf-skin-img"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/520030583/111fx57f"></div>
                                        <div class="cf-skin-name">M4A1-S | Cyrex (Factory New)
                                            <p>16.24 USD</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="cf-skin" style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #undefined">
                                            <div class="cf-skin-img"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1800001386/111fx57f"></div>
                                            <div class="cf-skin-name">AWP | Electric Hive (Minimal Wear)
                                                <p>14.82 USD</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thats how I would like it

```
<div class="cf-creator-skins">
    <div class="cf-skin" style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #undefined">
        <div class="cf-skin-img"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1611092744/111fx57f"></div>
        <div class="cf-skin-name">AWP | Lightning Strike (Factory New)
            <p>62.32 USD</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cf-skin" style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #eb4b4b">
        <div class="cf-skin-img"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/312020315/111fx57f"></div>
        <div class="cf-skin-name">★ Flip Knife | Safari Mesh (Battle-Scarred)
            <p>51.7 USD</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cf-skin" style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #undefined">
        <div class="cf-skin-img"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1815976823/111fx57f"></div>
        <div class="cf-skin-name">M4A1-S | Mecha Industries (Well-Worn)
            <p>21.56 USD</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cf-skin" style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #undefined">
        <div class="cf-skin-img"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/469585294/111fx57f"></div>
        <div class="cf-skin-name">AK-47 | Vulcan (Well-Worn)
            <p>21.46 USD</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cf-skin" style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #undefined">
        <div class="cf-skin-img"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1011942928/111fx57f"></div>
        <div class="cf-skin-name">AWP | Hyper Beast (Well-Worn)
            <p>21.41 USD</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cf-skin" style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #undefined">
        <div class="cf-skin-img"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1011942928/111fx57f"></div>
        <div class="cf-skin-name">AWP | Hyper Beast (Well-Worn)
            <p>21.41 USD</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cf-skin" style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #undefined">
        <div class="cf-skin-img"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1812959668/111fx57f"></div>
        <div class="cf-skin-name">M4A4 | Desolate Space (Minimal Wear)
            <p>18.16 USD</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cf-skin" style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #undefined">
        <div class="cf-skin-img"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1440505236/111fx57f"></div>
        <div class="cf-skin-name">AK-47 | Point Disarray (Minimal Wear)
            <p>17.82 USD</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cf-skin" style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #undefined">
        <div class="cf-skin-img"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/520030583/111fx57f"></div>
        <div class="cf-skin-name">M4A1-S | Cyrex (Factory New)
            <p>16.24 USD</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cf-skin" style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #undefined">
        <div class="cf-skin-img"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1800001386/111fx57f"></div>
        <div class="cf-skin-name">AWP | Electric Hive (Minimal Wear)
            <p>14.82 USD</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code misses a closing div, at the end of the line <div class="cf-skin"....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have missed closing div

```
data.creator[0].items.forEach(function (kevin){
    skins_creator.push('<div class="cf-skin" style="box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #'+kevin.color+'"> <div class="cf-skin-img"><img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/'+kevin.classid+'/111fx57f"></div><div class="cf-skin-name">'+kevin.name+'<p>'+kevin.price+' USD</p></div></div>');
});
```

Try this out

Comment: Thanks man, I remember when I tried it first time then it didn't work it showed me error and I though I had one closing div too much lol...

Answer (score 0):

In `skins_creator.push` You are missing a closing `</div>`